# How should I do to make DebugPage in only development environment?

Tags: laravel

I am using a Laravel 7.0.
I am looking for a good way to display debug pages in only Debug environment?
How should I do to hide in production environment?

```
Route::resource('/debug', 'DebugController')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple controllers / resources that you want to apply this check you could create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#introduction) and apply it in the routes.

Something like this:

```
Route::resource('/debug', 'DebugController')->middleware(['auth', 'debug');
```

If you need this check only in this controller you could do a simple middleware closure in the constructor instead.

Something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class DebugController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            if (app()->environment() === 'production') {
                abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
            }

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

This would return a 403 response if the environment is `production` but it would let the request through in `development`, `local`, `testing` etc.